# How to Make Every Image on a Page Fade In on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm polishing up one of my websites, and I would like to add in an effect to all the images on my page so they all fade in when the user scrolls down to each respective image.

I've seen several posts concerning this effect, but they all deal with only fading in one particular image.

Is there a way to have ALL the images on a page fade in when the user scrolls down to each one?

I've got quite a few images on this page, but I didn't want to have to go into each one and copy/paste the code to add the effect to each image individually if I can get away with it.

Bonus points for anyone who could also help me figure out how to reverse the effect when the user scrolls up.

This way, if the user scrolls back to the top (or another section of the page) all the images that have already faded in all fade back out once they are completely out of view.

This way, if the user decides to scroll back down, they get the same image fade in effect each time they scroll through the page.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I don't have any working code to achieve this effect yet, as I haven't found even a partial solution to this exact issue. Sorry.

Comment: I'm not picky when it comes to how to achieve this - CSS, JavaScript, a combination of the two, etc.

Comment: you can use some lazyload plugin with that effect or write something in JS that checks for scrolling and then checks for img elements in the viewport and finally animates them.

Comment: A quick search for "javascript fade in images on scroll" revealed many solutions such as http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qad/.

Answer (score 0):

You could check on the scroll event if the offset of a image is reached, and them show the image, on the contrary you can make it work for hidding ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like Wow.js. It is very easy to implement.

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/